# Create a WordPress plugin that converts html file to readable text document

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, plugins

I am a front-end developer and I need help to figure out how to create a plugin for WordPress that converts HTML files that are uploaded in the WordPress media section to a readable text document for the reading online option.

for example, the website provides three file formats to download a book in which the HTML format is also available. But the website also needs to provide an option to read the book online without downloading. Once the user clicks the read online option, it will open in a new tab with a user interface just like a pdf viewer except it not. It will have also have an option to navigate to different chapters and paragraphs.

For reference, what kind of web app I am talking about, Here a link that: https://www.bahai.org/library/authoritative-texts/bahaullah/call-divine-beloved/

once you click the options in the read online section you will redirect to that specific paragraph or title.

I want to make the same web app for a WordPress website in PHP. I want to know what resources will need to build it. Kindly guide me about it so that I can learn and explore options.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple solution (customize it)

1- add new endpoint

```
add_action( 'init', 'account_page_endpoint' );
function account_page_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'book', EP_ROOT );
}
```

2- add query var

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
function add_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'book';
    return $vars;
}
```

3- add custom page template (HtmlToText.php) in theme root and add new page with this template (Dashboard)

4- redirect book endpoint to custom page template

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if( get_query_var( 'book', false ) !== false ){
        get_template_part('HtmlToText');
        die;
    }
    return;
} );
```

5- use this url: https://msa.biawp.ir/book/bahaullah/chapter1/

6- manage url in custom page template

```
$book = explode('/', get_query_var('book'));

$bookName = $book[0];
$bookFile = $book[1];

readfile('https://msa.biawp.ir/wp-content/uploads/chapter1.html');
```

Comment: I understood a little bit what you have done and thank you for the demo. I will let you know once I try it out. Can you explain the explode function? What it does with $book.

Comment: You must seprate two parts of url: bahaaullah is your book name and chapter1 is your html file name. explode function seprates that. this url structure is like your link example. www.bahai.org

Comment: As you have shown steps, I have put the 3 hooks which are in points 1, 2, 4 in the function.php file. Then created HtmlToText template and put the code of point 6. Replace the link with my media Html file. Now the question is from where I will be redirected to text document? In point 5 the link contains /book/bahaullah/, what is that for? is it custom post type? Can you explain in a bit detail.

Comment: No, book is not a post type and dont create it, simply create a post as book details. enter details and some links (chapters pages) with https://msa.biawp.ir/book/bahaullah/chapter1/ format. bahaullah is you book name (any name you want). and add your html fila name after this. if your file is chapter1.html, enter chapter1. continue is url management in HtmlToText file. get url and read file. any question? i am